# How to get the list of ansible special variables (a.k.a magic variables) from the command line?

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a way to get the full list of ansible special variables in offline mode, from the command line and NOT from the ansible documentation webpage (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

Maybe using ansible-doc or some ansible tricks ?

Thank you !

Comment: [This function](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/91319c5cfc523fb9dfb343be81ff373ec394818a/lib/ansible/vars/manager.py#L449) in Ansible source code looks like a pretty good entry point for your hunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Zeitounator.

In my case, this command did the trick :

```
grep "variables\['" $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/vars/manager.py | cut -d "'" -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

little changes with @W4hf command:

```
grep "variables\['" $(ansible --version | awk '/ansible python module location/{print $NF"/vars/manager.py"}') |  cut -d "'" -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exhaustive since the list would depend on architecture and OS, but [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) has an example snippet which works as a list.

The data structure shown has many variables which are not in the list at the "Special Variables" page.